# How can i remove an object in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, python-3.7

i'm trying to create a chess simulator.

consider this scenario:
there is a black rook (instance object of `Rook` class) in square 2B called `rook1`.
there is a white rook in square 2C called `rook2`.

when the player moves `rook1` to square 2C , the i should remove `rook2` object from memory completely.

how can i do it?

P.S. i'v already tried `del rook2` , but i don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Python has automatic memory management. Generally, you shouldn't have to worry about this unless *you are keeping references around to the object in question*. Without a [mcve] it is not possible to help you other than to speak in generalities.

Comment: We need more information about your code, in order to help you :)

Answer (score 4):

Trying to remove objects from memory is the wrong way to go. Python offers no option to do that manually, and it would be the wrong operation to perform anyway.

You need to alter whatever data structure represents your chess board so that it represents a game state where there is a black rook at c2 and no piece at b2, rather than a game state where there is a black rook at b2 and a white rook at c2. In a reasonable Python beginner-project implementation of a chess board, this probably means assigning to cells in a list of lists. No objects need to be manually removed from memory to do this.

Having `rook1` and `rook2` variables referring to your rooks is unnecessary and probably counterproductive.

Comment: Agreed, your data structure needs a way to represent a piece as taken/removed from the board instead of clearing it from memory.